# Objective-C - 'sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(NSArray *)deviceCheck:(NSString *)device
    {
        NSString *deviceRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?device=%@",webservice,device];
        NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:deviceRequestString];
        NSURLResponse* response = nil;
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONURL];

        NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
        if(data == nil)
            return nil;
        NSError *myError;
        NSArray *tableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];
        return tableArray;
    }
```

but I keep getting this warning:

```
sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:] (see NSURLSession.h
```

on this line:

```
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
```

I tried changing to to the following:

```
NSData* data = [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:request];
```

and

```
NSData* data = [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
```

both gave me errors saying:

No known class method

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `NSURLSession`,your code may like this

```
-(void)deviceCheck:(NSString *)device Completetion:(void (^) (NSArray * result,NSError * error))completion{
NSString *deviceRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?device=%@",webservice,device];
NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:deviceRequestString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONURL];
NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [
      [NSURLSession sharedSession]
      dataTaskWithRequest:request
      completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          if(data == nil) {
              completion(nil,error);
              return;
          }
          NSError *myError;
          NSArray *tableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];
          completion(tableArray,myError);
      }
];
[dataTask resume];
}
```

Then when you use it

```
[self deviceCheck:@"123" Completetion:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {
   //Here use result,and check the error
}];
```

Note,this method is async

Comment: I tried calling it like so `[self deviceCheck:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name] Completetion:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {
            if(error == nil){
                
                NSLog(@"Here");
                
            }else{
                
                NSLog(@"Here 2");
            }
        }];` but that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

If you really need synch request (and you probably shouldn't have that), you can use :

```
+ (instancetype)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL
                          options:(NSDataReadingOptions)mask
                            error:(NSError * _Nullable *)errorPtr
```